# SUM values in one column if criteria exists at least once per value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    |    A      B             C                 D        |    E          F       |     G        H
----|----------------------------------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------
1   |                                                    |                       |    
2   |        Products        date            quantity    |                       |
----|----------------------------------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------
3   |        Product_A       2020-01-08          0       |   From     2020-01-01 |  Result:     800
4   |        Product_A       2020-12-15          0       |   to       2020-10-31 |
5   |        Product_A       2020-12-23          0       |                       |
6   |        Product_A                         500       |                       |
----|----------------------------------------------------|-----------------------|------------------
7   |        Product_B       2020-11-09          0       |                       | 
8   |        Product_B       2021-03-14          0       |                       |
9   |        Product_B                         700       |                       |
----|----------------------------------------------------|-----------------------|------------------
10  |        Product_C       2020-02-05          0       |                       |
11  |        Product_C       2020-07-19          0       |                       |
12  |        Product_C       2020-09-18          0       |                       |
13  |        Product_C       2020-09-25          0       |                       |
14  |        Product_C                         300       |                       |
14  |                                                    |                       |
15  |                                                    |                       |
```

---

In the table I have listed different products with multiple dates per product. 
Below each product there is a row in which a quantity is displayed.

Now in `Cell H3` I want to get the `Sum` of the quantity of all products that have **at least one date** between the dates in `Cell F3` and `Cell F4`. In the example this applies to `Product_A` and `Product_C` therefore the sum is `500+300=800`.

I have no clue what kind of formula I need to achieve this. 
I guess it must be something like this:

```
SUMIFS(Date in Cell F3 OR in Cell F4 exists for Product in Column C THEN SUM over Column D)
```

Do you have an idea how this formula has to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be with `SUMPRODUCT()` combined with `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(B3:B14,B3:B14,C3:C14,">="&F3,C3:C14,"<="&F4)>0)*D3:D14)
```